# removeChild() not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to display a message once the form has been submitted and remove the form from the page.

The first part of the script is working, but the second one (where I try to remove the form) does not.

Any suggestions?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("footer") > -1) {
       document.getElementById("thanksForMessage").innerHTML = "<h2>Thanks for the message. I will contact you shortly.</h2>";
       var formDiv = document.getElementById("formwell");
       var childForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
       formDiv.removeChild(childForm);
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and pure DOM? Why not use jQuery for the whole thing?

Comment: I'm more familiar with DOM, tried to use jQuery, but it did not work...

Comment: @Scimonster btw, how would you write this using just jQuery? Would you include the alternative version of the script in your answer? thanks!

Comment: Basically how Abdallh Abukhader did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var childForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
```

This returns a NodeList (like an array), not a single element. `removeChild` expects a single element. You can pass just the first one by:

```
   formDiv.removeChild(childForm[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("footer") > -1) {
   $("#thanksForMessage").html("<h2>Thanks for the message. I will contact you shortly.</h2>");
   var formDiv = $("#formwell");
   var childForm = "form";
   formDiv.remove(childForm);
}
```

});

Comment: It's missing a `t` in `#hanksForMessage`. Is that the problem, @AlexNowak?

Comment: @Scimonster now only the message works. The form's still there.

Comment: I noticed that and I fixed it, the code did not work anyway.. there must be something else..

Comment: this code similar of yours with just right down footer in the input and you will see the result after clicking the button